# How can i manage only stores based on my clientId? Nestjs

Tags: javascript, nestjs

My app used nestJs and mongoose, i have multiple ressources with **relations on my client**.

For this example i only take `Client`, and `Store`.
Each Store is related to a Client, so in my store i have the following data:

```
{
        "_id": "6582d34c0b52939c2d51402a",
        "clientId": "6556764d7bd208634371bf20",
        "name": "store Name",
}
```

My route for the two ressources are `/clients` and `/clients/:id/stores`.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { RouterModule } from '@nestjs/core'

import { PublicClientModule } from '@framework/features/clients/public/client.module'
import { PrivateClientModule } from '@framework/features/clients/private/client.module'
import { PublicStoreModule } from '@framework/features/stores/public/store.module'
import { PrivateStoreModule } from '@framework/features/stores/private/store.module'

const router = [
  {
    path: 'public',
    children: [
      {
        path: '/clients',
        module: PublicClientModule,
        children: [
          {
            path: '/:id',
            children: [
              {
                path: '/stores',
                module: PublicStoreModule,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '/clients',
        module: PrivateClientModule,
        children: [
          {
            path: '/:id',
            children: [
              {
                path: '/stores',
                module: PrivateStoreModule,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]

@Module({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.register(router),
    PublicClientModule,
    PrivateClientModule,
    PublicStoreModule,
    PrivateStoreModule,
  ],
})
export class FrameworkRouterModule {}
```

I have others ressources like `Stores` related on the `clients/:id/...` too.

Inside my controller Store i can obviously check if the clientId is the one related too the store, but i will have to do it in each function, for each ressources ... so it seems to me that is not the good way to do it.

There is for example my PrivateStoreController:

```
import { Controller, Res, Post, HttpStatus, Body, Put, Param, Delete } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Response } from 'express'

import { PrivateStoreService } from './store.service'
import { CreateStoreDto } from './dto/createStore.dto'
import { UpdateStoreDto } from './dto/updateStore.dto'

@Controller('')
export class PrivateStoreController {
  constructor(private readonly storeService: PrivateStoreService) {}

  @Post()
  async createStore(@Body() storeDto: CreateStoreDto, @Res() response: Response) {
    const store = await this.storeService.createStore(storeDto)
    return response.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).json(store)
  }

  @Put('/:id')
  async updateStore(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() storeDto: UpdateStoreDto, @Res() response: Response) {
    // I can check here if the client have access to this store
    const store = await this.storeService.updateStore(id, storeDto)
    return response.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(store)
  }

  @Delete('/:id')
  async deleteStore(@Param('id') id: string, @Res() response: Response) {
    const store = await this.storeService.deleteStore(id)
    return response.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(store)
  }
}
```

So, what is the common way to handle things only on the related scope (client in my case)?